(Topcase) Can I use a cellophane tape to attach the part where it needs an extra adhesive?
I have a plan to use a cellophane tape to attach the button-looking plug (the orange circle on picture)  on the top case to prevent physical disconnection from the inside while I’m using the machine. The tape that I will use is just a normal transparent tape that you can easily find from anywhere such as at school, a company or home etc.
What I’m worrying about is malformation of the tape by heat inside of the top case. Eventually, the battery pack and the plug don’t physically contact wach other, but I don’t want to use the tape on uncertain situation.
Will the battery heat melt down the cellophane tape and cause any potential damage on the machine?


Probably best to either find some tape that is known to be heat-resistant; or test a sample of the tape you have.

@benwiggy i didn’t think that way. Thank you for your comment.
